# How do I flip the output?

Tags: java

My question is: "How do I flip the Ouput of my Converter with an Array?"
The output of the program is correct but backwards.
We have to use arrays but I don't know how to include this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int input;
    var scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    char wh='x';

    do{
        System.out.println("Welche Zahl wollen Sie in hexadezimaler Schreibweise:");
        input = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(input+" D -> ");
        while(input>0){

            int Rest=input%16;


            switch(Rest){
                case 0 -> System.out.print("0");
                case 1 -> System.out.print("1");
                ...
                case 14 -> System.out.print("E");
                case 15 -> System.out.print("F");
            }


            input=input/16;
        }
        System.out.print(" H");

        do{
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Wollen Sie wiederholen?(J/N)");
            wh = scan.next().charAt(0);
        }while ((wh != 'J') && (wh != 'j') && (wh != 'N') && (wh != 'n'));
    }while ((wh == 'J') || (wh=='j'));
}
```

The Input is also right and the calculating also but I need it backwards!
Can anyone help me?

Comment: *"We have to use arrays"* Then why aren't you doing that? Instead of printing the hex digits immediately, store them in a `char[]`, then iterate the array backwards to print in the order you want.

Comment: yeah i know but how schould I do this?

Comment: That is the thing I asked how to do!

Comment: This seems to be a general question about arrays in Java.  The Java language tutorial has a guide on arrays: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Just store your output in string, instead of adding characters as suffix, add prefix :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int input;
    var scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    char wh='x';

    do{
    
        String output = "";
        System.out.println("Welche Zahl wollen Sie in hexadezimaler Schreibweise:");
        input = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(input+" D -> ");
        while(input>0){

            int Rest=input%16;

            if(Rest >=0 && Rest <=9){
                output= ""+Rest + output;
            } else {
                int r = (Rest - 10);
                int c = (int)('A') + r;
                output= ((char)c) + output;
            }

            input=input/16;
        }
        System.out.print(output +" H");

        do{
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Wollen Sie wiederholen?(J/N)");
            wh = scan.next().charAt(0);
        }while ((wh != 'J') && (wh != 'j') && (wh != 'N') && (wh != 'n'));
    } while ((wh == 'J') || (wh=='j'));
}
```